# Creating a boxplot in MatPlotLib using Titanic Dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, kaggle

From the [Titanic Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) from Kaggle, I'm trying to create a boxplot using the package `matplotlib.pyplot` using the age parameter as my basis. So I used the following code:

```
plt.boxplot(dataframe.age)
plt.show()
```

Only to get a blank graph:

[image]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Please let me know.

A lot of people on the internet use the `seaborn` package to do this. I accept using `seaborn` is an easier method, but currently, I am learning specifically about `matplotlib.pyplot` (I'm still a newbie to this), so I would need my code to be accordingly.

Thanks for understanding and for your help in advance!

Comment: My guess is it's an issue with the dataset. Have you looked at the dataframe to make sure you're using a proper column name? A quick view at the website shows the name may be "Age" not "age"?

Comment: @ramzikai The dataset I actually got actually has all the headers in lowercase. So that wasn't the problem. The link was just a reference.

Comment: `seaborn` is just a high-level API for `matplotlib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of missing values in the `Age` column of the Titanic data set. Either remove those rows, or fill the values with a default before creating a boxplot.

```
plt.boxplot(data['Age'].fillna(0.0))
```

[image: Titanic Age boxplot]

Comment: Ohh ok I get it. I remember trying to fill the NaN values to no avail, but your answer has helped me. Thanks :)